# Chrome extension onclick issue

Tags: google-chrome

I want to create an extension that reacts to a click that searches for all the `<ul>`'s in the page, and surround them with a border. The problem is that the code doesn't work, and clicking on the extension icon doesn't search for anything.

mainfest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background1.html" ,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"  
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*","https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

background1.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function ul_checker(){
        $('ul').addClass('ul_style');
        $('ul').append('<div class="close">X</div>');
        $('.close').addClass('style2');         
    }
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
{code:"ul_checker()"});

});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your extension is of type **content script**. You will have to specify what scripts will run on the page, see the manifest and description of the official [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). I assume that you will have to include jquery as a content script :).

Therefore, accordingly to the documentation you will have to add the following in your manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: The OP forgot to use inline code formatting and caused SO to strip out the `<ul>` in his post. You might want to review this question in light of the edit I made.

Comment: Gotcha, I edited my answer. I assume that your problem is only in the manifest :).